# Remove View from LinearLayout in Android issue

Tags: android

I created a LinearLayout that has ImageViews added dynamically to it. I can have a list of 50 ImageViews but only 3 will be shown in it at the same time.

I need to reference the 3 items in it so I have private variables setup at the top of my activity called ImageView item1, item2, item3.

When a button is pressed, the next ImageView in the list is added to the layout and the first item is removed. I then reset the references for item1, item2, and item3.

My problem is that while it works good, there seems to be a painting issue. item3 (the last ImageView) will show the new item added on top of the previous ImageView. It seems to be a painting issue because if I flip my phone into landscape mode and then go back to portrait, the issue is resolved.

Edit: I have tried adding .invalidate() to the layout and to the imageViews themselves with no luck.

Comment: Paste the relevant code & screenshots

Comment: Try `invalidate()` method for your view and also make sure the view you have deleted is nomore visible by settings its visibility to `View.GONE` if its not null.

Comment: Instead of removing and replacing views. Why not just recycle them? Meaning instead of moving the actual views just swap their content.  Much like you would do in an ArrayAdapter

Comment: you are doing it in this order right? add the new, remove the old, invalidate the layout. Try this order.

Comment: @slayton that was the right solution, many thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Well try to make the refresh the reference in this manner.

```
    layout.removeAllViews();
    layout.refreshDrawableState();
```

and then add the new 3 items to the LinearLayout. Hope this helps. :)

Comment: This is the proper way of doing it. No need to call `refreshDrawableState()` though because `removeAllViews()` does `requestLayout()` and `invalidate(true)` internally